# Resume viewport cycles rendering

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

How to resume the cycles rendering in viewport as in my case it is showing 'Rendering paused'. If it is to do with some additional settings than please ask me but help fix this because I have to render image every time to view what is going on![image]

Answer (score 9):

To resume preview render, click the icon that resembles a "play button" at the top of the viewport next to the overlays.

[image]